# Button Function Working Without Click

Tags: html

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
  function phase2Function(){
    document.getElementById("0").onclick = buttonChangeFunction();
    }
  function buttonChangeFunction(){
    document.getElementById("1").disabled = "true";
    }
</script>
<button id="0" onclick="numberFunction(0)">0</button>
<button id="1" onclick="numberFunction(1)">1</button>
```

I have a problem  with the above code that makes the "buttonChangeFunction" work without me clicking 0. The project im working on is a calculator, where after you press a math operator, it starts phase2Function. Edit: The Question Has been Answered, but I was wondering what to do if I actually want to put something in between the parentheses of buttonChangeFunction?

Comment: You're assigning the _result_ of calling `buttonChangeFunction` to the `onclick` handler of the element.

Comment: I'm generally new to coding, so, how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the parenthesis after `buttonChangeFunction` in `phase2Function`.

What you are trying to do is make buttonChangeFunction fire each time the button with the ID of '0' is clicked.

Instead, what you're actually doing, is calling buttonChangeFunction, getting back an undefined result (since the function doesn't `return` anything) and then setting the click handler of the id=0 element to this undefined result.

So, simply change:
`document.getElementById("0").onclick = buttonChangeFunction();`

to

`document.getElementById("0").onclick = buttonChangeFunction;`