# Set a parameter when changing a button onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html

Yesterday I made this post: [Button Function Working Without Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51643340/button-function-working-without-click/51643497#51643497), trying to figure out why my code wasn't working for a `document.getElementById("examplebutton").onclick = function();`, but the problem is I can't set parameters on the `function()` because the parentheses would make the button auto-fire.

Does anyone know how to put parameters in a line of code similar to this:

```
<button id="button" onclick="function1">BIG BUTTON THING</button>
 document.getElementById("button").onclick=function2
```

(I would want the parameter set to be for function 2)?

Comment: `.onclick = function2.bind(this, param1, param2, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a closure. Just wrap you function call into another one.

```
var myButton = document.getElementById("examplebutton");
myButton.onclick = function(){
    myButtonFunction('some parameters');
};

function myButtonFunction(param){
    console.log(param);
}
```